# rails db:migrate not working (psql (10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)) ) Windows 10

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu

I can not create or migrate my database because I keep getting this error message

```
fe_sendauth: no password supplied                                                                                       
Couldn't create 'coins-app-backend_development' database. Please check your 
configuration.                              
rails aborted!                                                                                                          
PG::ConnectionBad: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

I never created a password when I made the DB, is there a default?

database.yml file has this:

```
development:
<<: *default
database: coins-app-backend_development

# The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
# To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
# When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
# the same name as the operating system user that initialized the database.
#username: coins-app-backend

# The password associated with the postgres role (username).
#password:

# Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
# domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
# domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
host: 127.0.0.1

port: 5433
```

Comment: It looks like your Postgres server is not running.

Comment: I updated the error message in my post with the server running. Still not working

Comment: @rgc998 check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well... if you are sure your PostgreSQL server is running, you need to specify the database hostname, because windows does not support domain sockets.

So, open `config/database.yml` and under "default" section add: `host: 127.0.0.1`.

So you will have something like:

```
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  host: 127.0.0.1
```

Actually, if you look at comments on that file (`config/database.yml`), you will see:

> Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses
>   a domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not
>   have domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.

EDIT:

Now that you are getting a new error, you need to update your `pg_hba.conf` PostgreSQL configuration file, changing the `md5` to `trust`